# Dynamic checkboxes not loading

Tags: angular, typescript, checkbox, formbuilder

I have a group of checkboxes of 'business units' loaded from the database upon which I want to perform validation.

As I have it setup at the moment they are not displaying even though the values did return from the db successfully.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.commServe.getBusinessUnitsOnly().subscribe((data) => {
        this.businessUnits = data;
    },
        (error) => {
            this.errorMessage = <any>error;
        })
}
```

the formgroup is initialized in the constructor

```
this.registrationForm = fb.group({

        "firstName": new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        "lastName": new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        "password": new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        "confirmPassword": new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
        bUnits: this.fb.array(
            this.businessUnits.map(() => this.fb.control('')),
            CustomValidators.multipleCheckboxRequireOne
        )

    })
```

this is the markup

```
 <div formArrayName="bUnits">
    <div class="checkbox"*ngFor="let unit of registrationForm.controls.bUnits.controls; let i = index;">
      <label><input type="checkbox" #instance  formControlName="i" (click)="getCheckBoxValue(instance.checked, businessUnits[i].BuName)">{{ businessUnits[i].BuName}}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Why are the values not displaying? 
How can I go about in rectifying this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the constructor is called before `ngOnInit`. This means that your form gets created before your data loads. Since you didn't say anything about an error I suspect that you are initializing `businessUnits` to be an empty Array.

One way to fix your issue is to move your initialization logic to the subscribe. This will ensure that the data is loaded:

```
this.commServe.getBusinessUnitsOnly().subscribe((data) => {
    this.businessUnits = data;
    this.registrationForm
        .setControl("bUnits", this.fb.array(
            this.businessUnits.map(() => this.fb.control('')),
            CustomValidators.multipleCheckboxRequireOne))
},
    (error) => {
        this.errorMessage = <any>error;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the `formControlName` that references an array item should just be the index:

```
  <label><input type="checkbox" #instance  [formControlName]="i" (click)="getCheckBoxValue(instance.checked, businessUnits[i].BuName)">{{ businessUnits[i].BuName}}</label>
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html#!#form-array

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/LSX6VRoyKJ9uMNxCmmJ6?p=preview)

```
formControlName="i"
```

should be

```
[formControlName]="i"
```

otherwise the string `'i'` will be used as name instead of the index.

Comment: I fixed it thanks. values still dont render and no error